# Node.js cant log Class model data from Student model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am having an issue here. I currently am making a school directory using node.js and MongoDB. I am in an app.post request and for some reason I can't get the name of the class being linked to the student to log to the console, but createdClass.name will print...

Here is the code...

```
app.post("/students/:id", function(req, res){
   Student.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundStudent){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          Class.create(req.body.class, function(err, createdClass){
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                  createdClass.student.id = foundStudent._id;
                  createdClass.student.name = foundStudent.name;
                  console.log(createdClass);
                  createdClass.save();

                  foundStudent.classes.push(createdClass);
                  console.log(foundStudent.classes[0].name);
                  foundStudent.save();
              }
          });
       }
   });
   res.redirect("/students/" + req.params.id);
});
```

Also, here are my models...

STUDENT:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: String,
        classes: [
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Class"
                }
            ],
        grades: Array
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

CLASS:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var classSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: String,
        student: 
        {
            id: 
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Student"
            },
            name: String
        }
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Class", classSchema);
```

Thank you in advance and please do let me know if there is anything I can add to make this easier to read.

Here is the page making the post request...

```
<div>
    <h1>Student Profile</h1>
    <h2>Name: <%=student.name%></h2>
    <div>
        <h3>Classes:
            <form action="/students/<%= student._id %>" method="POST">
                <%if(student.classes.length === 0){%>
                    <p>No classes linked to profile, please add class..</p>
                    <input type="text" name="class[name]" placeholder="Class name">
                <% } else { %>
                    <% student.classes.forEach(function(course){ %>
                        <li><%= course.name %></li>
                    <% }); %>
                <% } %>
            </form>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Class is a reserved word and can't be used for a variable

Comment: Thank you, I updated this but it still doesn't work 