# Logging the name of an object within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
student = {
    classes: [
        name: "Studies"
    ]
};
```

I can't get the following to log anything but `undefined`. Any idea why?

```
console.log(student.classes[0].name);
```

Comment: Uhh, what are you doing with that array? Did you mean to have an object *inside the array?*: `student = { classes: [ { name: "Studies" } ] }`?

Comment: `student = { classes: { name: "Studies" } };` or ?

Comment: It's actually a small section of Code using node.js, I asked another question involving the whole code but got no responses. I figured maybe it was just a complicated question so I tried to simplify it. Basically I have a db and every student has classes and every class has students. They are linked together using mongoose models but for some reason I can't access the class name from within the student. For example, console.log(student.courses[0].name) will log undefined but console.log(course.name) will log the actual name.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto that would depend on what data you bring back with your query.

Comment: I'm going to link my question in here so you can see the full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396420/node-js-cant-log-class-model-data-from-student-model

Comment: Given that this is invalid syntax, I'm not sure how you even get to the point of *trying* to access anything in that object…

Answer (score 3):

You need an array for `classes` and an object for a single class.

```
student = { classes: [ { name: "Studies"} ] };
```